# Completing intervals and filling column

Tags: r, data.table

I have data like this:

```
set.seed(4597)
lower = sort(runif(10L))
upper = c(lower[-1], 1)

# randomly drop some intervals from the "complete" data 
#   (which is in practice "unknown")
obs = cbind(lower, upper)[-sample(10, 4), ]

library(data.table)
# augment with a column associated to each interval
DT = data.table(obs)[ , v := rpois(.N, 10)]
DT[]
#         lower     upper  v
# 1: 0.08810018 0.1026903  7
# 2: 0.31929301 0.4530299  6
# 3: 0.45302992 0.5248329  6
# 4: 0.58620724 0.8027425  9
# 5: 0.80274248 0.9054854 10
# 6: 0.98218176 1.0000000 10
```

Most of the intervals "line up" from row to row, except rows 1-2, 3-4, and 5-6.

I'd like to add rows for each of these cases, e.g. one with `lower = .102` and `upper` = `.319`, and set `v` to be `0` in each case.

To further complicate things, `lower` and `upper` have *numerical* differences, so testing `.453 == .453` (rows 3&4) may fail:

```
# adding random tiny noise
DT[ , upper := 
      upper + 
      sample(-1:1, .N, TRUE)*10^sample(0:2, .N, TRUE)*.Machine$double.eps]
```

My current approach seems quite messy; I'm wondering what other options might be more efficient (I've got to do this operation tens of thousands, if not millions, of times)

```
DT[ , {
  lower_lead = shift(lower, type = 'lead', fill = upper[.N])
  # "new" points come when the led value of lower 
  #   doesn't match upper (to numerical precision)
  new = abs(lower_lead - upper) > .0001
  # augment lower with the new point
  new_lower = c(lower, upper[new])
  # don't sort right away, need to keep indices to augment v
  idx = order(new_lower)
  new_lower = new_lower[idx]
  new_v = v[idx]
  new_v[is.na(new_v)] = 0
  # re-shift new_lower to get upper
  new_upper = shift(new_lower, type = 'lead', fill = upper[.N])
  .(lower = new_lower, upper = new_upper, v = new_v)
}]
#         lower     upper  v
# 1: 0.08810018 0.1026903  7
# 2: 0.10269026 0.3192930  0
# 3: 0.31929301 0.4530299  6
# 4: 0.45302992 0.5248329  6
# 5: 0.52483292 0.5862072  0
# 6: 0.58620724 0.8027425  9
# 7: 0.80274248 0.9054854 10
# 8: 0.90548543 0.9821818  0
# 9: 0.98218176 1.0000000 10
```

Is there a better way to do this?

---

Here's a test case at a larger scale:

```
set.seed(4597)
KK = 1e5
DT = data.table(ID = 1:KK)
DT = DT[ , {
  lower = sort(runif(10L))
  upper = c(lower[-1], 1)
  idx = sample(10, 4)
  .(lower = lower[-idx], upper = upper[-idx])
}, by = ID]
DT[ , v := rpois(.N, 10)]
DT[]

DT[ , upper := 
      upper + 
      sample(-1:1, .N, TRUE)*10^sample(0:2, .N, TRUE)*.Machine$double.eps]

system.time({
DT[ , {
  lower_lead = shift(lower, type = 'lead', fill = upper[.N])
  # "new" points come when the led value of lower 
  #   doesn't match upper (to numerical precision)
  new = abs(lower_lead - upper) > .0001
  # augment lower with the new point
  new_lower = c(lower, upper[new])
  # don't sort right away, need to keep indices to augment v
  idx = order(new_lower)
  new_lower = new_lower[idx]
  new_v = v[idx]
  new_v[is.na(new_v)] = 0
  # re-shift new_lower to get upper
  new_upper = shift(new_lower, type = 'lead', fill = upper[.N])
  .(lower = new_lower, upper = new_upper, v = new_v)
}, by = ID][]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.592   0.018   4.609
```

Comment: Running your code with that seed, I see different but similar results:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43326613#43326613

Comment: @Frank thanks, I must have gotten out of sync during iteration in prepping the example. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For x != shift(y) by group, you can use a trick to avoid `by=`:

```
system.time({
  # w are positions of a "lower" that is above the preceding "upper"
  w <- DT[(abs(lower - shift(upper)) > eps) & (rowid(ID) != 1L), which=TRUE]
  new = DT[, .(ID = ID[w], lower = upper[w-1L], upper = lower[w], v = 0L)]
  fres = rbind(DT, new)
  setkey(fres, ID, lower)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.050   0.012   0.061 

system.time({
mres = DT[ , {
  lower_lead = shift(lower, type = 'lead', fill = upper[.N])
  # "new" points come when the led value of lower 
  #   doesn't match upper (to numerical precision)
  new = abs(lower_lead - upper) > .0001
  # augment lower with the new point
  new_lower = c(lower, upper[new])
  # don't sort right away, need to keep indices to augment v
  idx = order(new_lower)
  new_lower = new_lower[idx]
  new_v = v[idx]
  new_v[is.na(new_v)] = 0L
  # re-shift new_lower to get upper
  new_upper = shift(new_lower, type = 'lead', fill = upper[.N])
  .(lower = new_lower, upper = new_upper, v = new_v)
}, by = ID][]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.447   0.025   4.471
```

It doesn't match exactly, but I think it's due to numerical error introduced in `mres`...

```
fsetequal(fres, mres)
# FALSE

DT[fres, on=.(ID, upper), .N, nomatch=0]
# [1] 600000
DT[mres, on=.(ID, upper), .N, nomatch=0]
# [1] 400092
```

That is, `mres` contains 199908 rows from `DT` with changed values (maybe using the `lower` from the next row instead of the original `upper`?).

Comment: awesome approach. I added in time to reorder this (which is still negligible).

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to create a vector of breakpoints from the given `lower` and `upper` and derive *all* potential intervals from the breakpoints which are joined with the given intervals. The gaps in the given data are indicated by `NA`.

Here, a modification is needed to remove intervals whose length is below a given epsilon.

```
eps <- 0.0001
DT[DT[, {tmp <- sort(c(lower, upper)); 
.(lower = head(tmp, -1L), upper = tail(tmp, -1L))}][
  upper - lower > eps], on = .(lower, upper)][is.na(v), v := 0][]
```

> ```
>        lower     upper  v
> 1: 0.1026903 0.2634059 14
> 2: 0.2634059 0.3192930  0
> 3: 0.3192930 0.4530299 11
> 4: 0.4530299 0.5248329 12
> 5: 0.5248329 0.5862072  5
> 6: 0.5862072 0.8027425  5
> 7: 0.8027425 0.9054854 15
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "#  i      lower     upper  v
# 1: 0.1026903 0.2634059 14
# 2: 0.3192930 0.4530299 11
# 3: 0.4530299 0.5248329 12
# 4: 0.5248329 0.5862072  5
# 5: 0.5862072 0.8027425  5
# 6: 0.8027425 0.9054854 15", drop = 1:2
)
set.seed(1L)
DT[ , upper := 
      upper + 
      sample(-1:1, .N, TRUE)*10^sample(0:2, .N, TRUE)*.Machine$double.eps]
```

Comment: See edit for a test case at a larger scale; this is about 20% slower than my approach, and also winds up with a different number of rows (I'm not sure why, but my first guess is it's due to numerical issues)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that gets close to how I initially conceptualized this problem, as "colliding" the `upper` and `lower_lead` vectors together and getting rid of duplicates. (side note: it'd be really nice if there was a `tol` parameter to `unique` ). It sidesteps what I think the biggest inefficiency in my initial approach is -- sorting, but I guess the patchwork on creating `new_v` rebalances that:

```
DT[ , {
  lower_lead = shift(lower, type = 'lead', fill = upper[.N])

  new_upper = lapply(seq_len(.N), function(ii) {
    if (abs(upper[ii] - lower_lead[ii]) > .0001) 
      c(upper[ii], lower_lead[ii])
    else upper[ii]
  })
  new_v = as.list(v)
  new_v[idx] = lapply(which(idx <- lengths(new_upper) > 1L), function(ii) c(v[[ii]], 0L))
  new_upper = unlist(new_upper)
  .(lower = shift(new_upper, fill = lower[1L]),
    upper = new_upper, v = unlist(new_v))
}, by = ID]
```